# retornar conteúdo específico com regex - POSTGRESQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, regex

Eu tenho a consulta abaixo, onde são capturados os 3 maiores processos que consomem memória na máquina. Gostaria que meu select exibisse apenas o pid e o nome do processo contido em `{name: }`

**SELECT NORMAL**

```
top_mem   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
12555, {memory_percent: 3.6073870265949464, name: code},10581, {memory_percent: 5.82421985505014, name: VirtualBoxVM},11518, {memory_percent: 13.986433224706513, name: java}
```

**SELECT DESEJADO (MATRIZ)**

```
12555, code
10581, VirtualBoxVM
11518, java
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT top_mem FROM tbl_top_consum_hosts WHERE (top_mem regexp '^name[a-z]')
```

Comment: hey olá!
no select normal tem apenas uma linha com todos os registos?
poderia mostrar a estrutura da tabela ?

Comment: Eu acho mais fácil tratar isso fora do SQL, qualquer linguagem possui funções que manipulam strings mais facilmente (e talvez sem precisar de regex, já que alguns splits devem resolver...)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, vou testar em python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(regexp_split_to_table('12555, {memory_percent: 3.6073870265949464, name: code},10581, {memory_percent: 5.82421985505014, name: VirtualBoxVM},11518, {memory_percent: 13.986433224706513, name: java}', '},*'), '([[:digit:]]{5}).*name: ([[:alpha:]]+$)', 'g');
```

Talvez possa simplificar com a função regexp_matches.